# Omniture Saint - Code execution seems successful. But not reflected in reports

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are trying to upload classification for Omniture report suites with Omniture API. The code runs successfully - A job is created, the job status is checked and a completion is reported.

```
Relation ID matched - report suite = 'xxxxxxxxxx', relation id = '51', relation name = 'Products'.
Job #4003318 populated. Report Suite ID='xxxxxxxxxx', Data Rows='196', Relation ID='51'.
COMMIT JOB : ID = '4003318', MESSAGE = 'Success'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:19:05.802000', check # = '0', status ='In Progress'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:19:17.224000', check # = '1', status ='In Progress'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:19:28.552000', check # = '2', status ='In Progress'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:19:39.906000', check # = '3', status = 'In Progress'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:19:51.559000', check # = '4', status = 'In Progress'
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:20:03.495000', check # = '5', status = 'In Progress - 0% Complete
Job ID = '4003318', time = '2014-01-21 17:20:15.101000', check # = '6', status = 'Completed'
Job ID # '4003318' has finished polling, with a status of 'Completed'.
```

However, the classification update is not reflected in the reports. It is a completed black box on the other end and we are not able to figure out why it is not showing up in the Omniture front end reports. We are trying to get help from Adobe support, but it has been slow. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used the API to upload classifications. I just generate a .tab/.fin file and ftp it the ftp location instead. In any case, how long has it been since the script ran? In my experience, it usually takes 1-2 days for the classifications to show up in reports, but I've seen it take upwards of a week in some cases...

Comment: oh i see a timestamp in there.. yeah i think i'd start to suspect something fishy too.. is this your first time trying to do it through the API, or has it normally worked before?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Crayon. We used to successfully upload the classification with OmnitureAPI.dll. That suddenly stopped working and there was no explanation or help from Omniture support. We had to switch over to using REST API. And never have been successful with it. We did wait for few days and have tried it for different report suites. Manual upload with the same dataset through browser works fine. Running the API instead of FTP is the preferred solution. So any thoughts on getting unblocked would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I've had troubles with the SOAP style API in the past and also switched to REST. So I'm afraid that I don't really have anything more to offer except for basic "double check you are sending to the right rsid, variable, column names, classification levels actually setup" etc. that you probably already checked :/

Comment: Also, not sure if I was clear or not, but you can automate sending via ftp. Dunno if you understood that and nonetheless prefer using the API  (I assume you did, but just making sure). I know doing it that way works, because I have set up many php scripts that generate .tab/.fin files and ftp to Omniture and they work.

Comment: If you hear back from Adobe, can you post their response? I'm interested in hearing about it. While I have not used the REST API to upload saint classifications, I *have* used it to retrieve and change the classification levels, and I had a devil of a time sorting that out. The manual is inconsistent and outright wrong in some places and try as I might, could not get a response from Adobe about it. So I started throwing darts in the dark and finally sorted  a workable solution for that. I was eventually going to look into next step of uploading class. *values* but your post makes me worry :(

Comment: Thanks, Crayon. Yes, I did understand that you are referring to an automated solution for FTP. But, uploading through API (when working well) is preferred. Adobe support is just not of any help (yet). Will post an update if get unblocked. Thanks.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? If not let me know and I will look into it.